# trying to send test configuration email but Failed to send out e-mail

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins i am using
email notification smtp server : smtp.gmail.com
username and password of my gmail
smtp port 465 and also i have installed email extension and email extension template but its throwing me error.

> Failed to send out e-mail
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>
> Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
> nested exception is:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing 'less secure app access' in google account settings!

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

If that doesn't work try allow access to google account from new device as well!

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha